# How do I create a new row in a dataframe once a condition is met?

Tags: r

I have a dataframe where I'd like to create a new row when a condition is met. In this case, a new row is created after 'DNP'.  The pattern is not a repeated pattern. The third row is not always incorrect. Ex:

```
incorrect_df <- data.frame(game=c(1:3,'2023-11-17'), 
  Date=c('2023-11-20','2023-11-19','2023-11-18','C'), 
  div=c(LETTERS[1:2],'DNP','18'), 
  stat=c(14,29,4,''))`

| game | Date | div | pts |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-11-20  | A | 14 |
| 2 | 2023-11-19 | B | 29 |
| 3 | 2023-11-18 | DNP | 4 |
| 2023-11-17 | C | 18 |  |

correct_df <- data.frame(game=c(1:3,4),
   Date=c('2023-11-20','2023-11-19','2023-11-18','2023-11-17'),
   div=c(LETTERS[1:2],'DNP',LETTERS[3]),
   stat=c(14,29,'',18))`

| game | Date | div | pts |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-11-20  | A | 14 |
| 2 | 2023-11-19 | B | 29 |
| 3 | 2023-11-18 | DNP |  |
| 4 | 2023-11-17  | C | 18 |
```

Comment: Unclear, what is the condition? What did you try to achieve the desired result?

Comment: Before import the file (or whatever your input is), add a separator after DNP.

Comment: Depends on whether you were the one to make the mistake of not importing the file correctly. Probably was a fixed field format file, and if so you should go back and fix the input specification.

Comment: I apologize for not clarifying the data source. The data comes from a webscrape, which comes across as a character vector. Perhaps by my own novice understanding.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution would be to fix this upstream somehow, perhaps by fixing the delimiters in your source file. If the columns come in misaligned, it's likely some of the data types will be wrong, since R will coerce them into a format (e.g. character) which will accommodate all the data. (For instance, 1:3 in game is numeric, but to hold "2023-11-17" as well, R will convert everything in that column to character data.) So you may want to do some cleanup afterwards to get the dates into Date format, the games into numeric, etc.

In this case, I assumed a condition for shifting would be the rows where `game` does not cleanly convert to numeric. ie convert to numeric, if that is NA, then that's a row that needs shifting.

```
shifted_rows = is.na(as.numeric(incorrect_df$game))
correct_df <- incorrect_df
for(r in 1:nrow(incorrect_df)) {
  if(shifted_rows[r]) {
    for(c in ncol(incorrect_df):2) {
      correct_df[r, c] <- correct_df[r, c-1]
    }
    correct_df[r, 1] = r
  }
}
```

Result

```
  game       Date div stat
1    1 2023-11-20   A   14
2    2 2023-11-19   B   29
3    3 2023-11-18 DNP    4
4    4 2023-11-17   C   18
```